# asp.net+bearer token: Tampering of claims possible?

Tags: asp.net, oauth2

I am experimenting with an OAuth2 authentication in an asp.net web-service.

When accidentally generating a huge amount of claims I've discovered that the bearer token increases drastically in size. That leads me to the assumption that the claims and possible other authorization related information will get stored in the bearer token.

(Previously I was under the impression that the bearer token is just another type of session-ID and the claims/roles where stored server-side)

My assumptions:

- The identity claims are stored in the bearer token and thereby accessible by the client.
- I feel encouraged by the developer guidelines (MSDN, StackOverFlow) to store identity related informations in the claims (e.g. "ClientID"=xxxx, "CanViewSensitiveData"=true, etc.). I considered it "state of the art".

The combination of the two points seem to be not right. To send/receive authentication/authorization sensitive data to/from the client would offer a possibility of a rogue client tampering with the bearer token and changing the contained claims/roles. Prior, with the usage of the sessionId, that was mitigated by a random generation of the sessionID and the huge entropy.

I am certain that the inventors of this technology/protocol already prevented the tampering of the contained data but I am not sure how. Could somebody shed some light on this matter? Are my assumptions wrong or is there some kind of token signing involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use an insecure homebrew setup of OAuth2, or you explicitly disable token validations; your *tokens are cryptographically signed* by the issuer.  As written in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523):

> The JWT MUST be digitally signed or have a Message Authentication Code (MAC) applied by the issuer.  The authorization server MUST reject JWTs with an invalid signature or MAC.

The downside of putting a lot of claims in your JWT token is that it could be "chopped off" if it exceeds some HTTP Header maximum length.  Apache is 8kB, IIS is 16kB.

So generally, stick to the use of (new) tested libraries and don't disable any token validation calls and you shouldn't have much to worry about.  If an adversary can "impersonate" a token issuer, then that's a different story.